# Health Check for ReactiveConsumer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, project-reactor

How to check for consumer health when using ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate template ?

for non-reactive we can use "KafkaMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()", similar to this is there anything in non-reactive ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built it, but you could use `metricsFromConsumer` and imply health by examining some of the metrics, e.g.

```
MetricName [name=network-io-total, group=consumer-metrics, description=The total number of network operations (reads or writes) on all connections
MetricName [name=connection-count, group=consumer-metrics, description=The current number of active connections.
```

etc.

Comment: ok, thank you. any documentation or example to refer to ?

Comment: See the Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_monitoring `last-poll-seconds-ago` might be a good one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gary, I have used the last-poll-seconds-ago for health checks, and successfully implemented it in my application. Please check this sample for your reference.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConsumerHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry     kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
private final AppPropertyConfig appPropertyConfig;

@Override
public Health health() {
    final Collection<MessageListenerContainer> allListenerContainers = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers();

    Optional<Double> pollInterval = allListenerContainers.stream()
            .map(MessageListenerContainer::metrics)
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().name().equalsIgnoreCase("last-poll-seconds-ago"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(metric -> (Double) metric.metricValue())
            .filter(value -> value > (Double.parseDouble(appPropertyConfig.getKafkaMaxPollInterval()) / 1000))
            .findFirst();

    pollInterval.ifPresent(value -> log.info("Delay in poll {} sec", value));

    Map<String, ConsumerDetails> consumersHealth = allListenerContainers.stream()
            .map(this::buildConsumerDetails)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ConsumerDetails::getName, Function.identity()));

    return Health.status(pollInterval.isEmpty() ? Status.UP : Status.DOWN)
            .withDetails(consumersHealth)
            .build();
}

private ConsumerDetails buildConsumerDetails(MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
    String partitions = messageListenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions().stream()
            .map(TopicPartition::partition)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    return ConsumerDetails.builder()
            .name(messageListenerContainer.getGroupId())
            .partitions(partitions)
            .running(messageListenerContainer.isRunning())
            .build();
}

@Getter
@Builder
private static class ConsumerDetails {
    String name;
    String partitions;
    boolean running;
}
}
```